# How can I use Dependency Injection for a property of a plugin, when type and instance of the property is part of a third party package?

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, moryx

I just startet to write some tests for my moryx project. Therefore I have to loosen some dependencies a bit. So I tried to inject a dependency of my plugin to a "third party" implementation. (It is not really third party, but it is in another project and I add it to my project via nuget.) So the interface and its implementation is part of the third party library.

Is there a way to register the interface and set its implementation to the Moryx.Runtime.Container, so that it will be injected? Or do I have to write a wrapper?

This is what I tried: (It is not working :))

```
[ServerModule(ModuleName)]
public class ModuleController : ServerModuleBase<ModuleConfig>
{
    //...
     protected override void OnInitialize()
     {
         Container.Register<IThirdPartyInterface>();
         var thirdPartyImplementation = new ThirdPartyImplementation();
         Container.SetInstance(thirdPartyImplementation);
     }
    //...
}

[Plugin(LifeCycle.Singleton, typeof(IMyPlugin), Name = nameof(MyPlugin))]
internal class MyPlugin: IMyPlugin
{
    public IThirdPartyInterface ThirdPartyImplementation {get;set;}
}
```

Btw: The DI works, if change the type of the property in `MyPlugin` to `ThirdPartyImplementation`, but I need the interface for testing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. First let me explain the misunderstanding or what went wrong.

When you use `Container.Register<IThirdPartyInterface>();` without an implementation, our container tries to register a factory. When using `SetInstance` without giving a type parameter, the generic is inferred from the argument and thereby registered under the class.

You can either register type and interface and let castle create an instance using [`Register<IThirdPartyInterface,ThirdPartyImplementation>()`](https://github.com/PHOENIXCONTACT/MORYX-Platform/blob/dev/src/Moryx.Container/CastleContainer.cs#L188) or you can use [`SetInstance<IThirdPartyInterface>(thirdPartyImplementation)`](https://github.com/PHOENIXCONTACT/MORYX-Platform/blob/dev/src/Moryx.Container/CastleContainer.cs#L236)